# Cannot extract ajax success function variable from response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, callback

I have an ajax call in view of MVC that calls one function which calls 5 other functions before completing.  Each function has an if/else to return its own error message if it fails and to show the error messages the original page needs to be reloaded.  But if there are no errors the ajax call should updated to the complete page.  I know a simple if/else statement in the success function will accomplish this and I put the same simple error variable in the fail of each function.  but I cannot pull the variable out of the success function response to use in the success function if/else statement.   my ajax call is below and im running php on the server side.

```
function sendstuff(data) {


                            $.ajax({
                                type:"POST",
                                datatype:'json',
                                cache: false,
                                data: data,
                                url:"/Orders/getitem/",
                                success:function(resp, status, jxr){
                                    alert(resp);
                                    if(resp.fail == "error") {
                                    // error handling, show data.message or what you want.
                                    location.reload(true);
                                } else {
                                    // same as above but with success
                                    $('body').html(resp);



                                }
                            });
                            return false;
                        };
```

Below is where the error is sending from

```
if ( $status != 201 ) { 
            // $this->Flash->error(__('There was an error with the entry. Please, try again.'));
            $ajaxerr['fail'] = 'error';
            echo json_encode($ajaxerr); 
            die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $result, curl_error " . curl_error($ch) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($ch));
```

and this is whats in the response because it loads else part of the success function every time.

```
{"fail":"error"}Error: call to URL https://api.blank failed with status 400, response {"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","details":[{"field":"blank.fng_ints[0].ct_issue","issue":"date cannot be in the past."}],"message":"Invalid request. See details.","information_link":"https://developer.api/#VALIDATION_ERROR","debug_id":"24f4"}, curl_error , curl_errno 0
```

I can see it's passing the var but i can't pull it out to be used in the success function if/else statement. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your server response is not a valid JSON response, so it wan't parse correctly, and therefore - wan't get to the success message

Change your server to something like

```
if ( $status != 201 ) { 
            // $this->Flash->error(__('There was an error with the entry. Please, try again.'));
            $ajaxerr['fail'] = 'error';
            $ajaxerr['msg'] = "Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $result, curl_error " . curl_error($ch) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($ch);
            echo json_encode($ajaxerr); 
            exit;
}
```

And then it would parse as

```
{
    "fail":"error",
    "msg":"..."
}
```

Anyway, if you have a server error, you better send a real error message from the server (using HTTP status >= 400) and then catch it in jQuery inside the `error` callback, instead of the `success` callback

```
$.ajax( {
 ...
   success: function() {
       //handle success request
   }, 
   error: function() {
       //handle failed requests
   }
})
```

Comment: Well the server is not actually erring.  I get a response from each call but if it's not accepted it lets the user know why.  Also I made the change you suggested and still not working.  when I alert resp.fail it shows undefined

Comment: What response do you get with the above code? You can use `console.log(resp);` for easier debugging. Just check your browser's developer tools console.

Comment: Errors sent by server are not necessarily server errors. Status `400 Bad Request` is commonly used to identify application error. (as opposed to `500 Internal Server Error` which should point on "real" server error - and should never happen in a perfect world

Comment: I removed everything else posting back but the fail and console.log shows {"fail":"error"}, but when I alert it still says undefined and it still is not triggering the if/else statement in my ajax success function

Answer (score 0):

The `die();` call is putting string output in your response, outside of the json structure, which causes your Ajax function to not be able to parse the response.

Consider doing this:

```
$ajaxerr['fail'] = 'error';
$ajaxerr['reason'] = "Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $result, curl_error " . curl_error($ch) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($ch);
 echo json_encode($ajaxerr); 
 die();
```

Comment: I switched my php to Yarons above and commented on his

Answer (score 0):

In your code your response is not json object because 'die' call produce output as well. So call `die();` without any parameters.

Comment: I switched my php code to Yarons above and commented

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this. all I had to do was set resp into a var  and I removed all unnessary   I feel like and idiot for wasting hours of my life but it is fixed.  Thank you all:) especially Yaron U.